# Vue 3: How to call function from another function in the same mutations.js in Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

In my mutations.js file, I happen to have one function calling another function in the same file.  Here's my sample code example:

```
export default {
  async addQuestionAnswer(state, payload) {
    alert(payload);
    this.updateSubjects(state);
    alert("This is never reached");
  },
  updateSubjects(state) {
    alert("This is never reached");
  },
}
```

Does anyone know how to call the updateSubjects function from the addQuestionAnswer function?  I've checked my console.log and found this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.updateSubjects is not a function
```

Comment: This is more of an action thing to do that IMO: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions But there is maybe a way to reference a sibling function like you want. You can't reference it as is?

Comment: @kissu My code is a bit more complicated, but I've narrowed it down to the alerts which says "This is never reached".  I'm puzzling over why the updateSubjects function is not called...

Comment: @kissu I've also used alerts in my code to help narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: Tbh, `alert` is quite bad as a debugging solution in an SPA. Try a regular `console.log` rather.

Comment: @kissu I've tried both removing and adding async to both functions, but it did not work either...

Comment: A mutation is sync, `async` will definitely not help.

Comment: @kissu, I'm using async because my function is fetching data from my Firebase server.  I've used console.log, thanks, and the result is this error:
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.updateSubjects is not a function`

Comment: Mutations **are sync**, this is mandatory. If you want something async, use **actions**. Also, `this` is probably not the way to go here, try without it. Finally, if you're using async, you could fallback to `actions` and chain other ones inside without any struggle. As in my initial comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @kissu, I've found the solution to my problem based on the console.log error I've posted with your suggestion.  Thanks.  I added this to my mutations.js file:

```
import store from '../store';
```

Then I changed this:

```
this.updateSubjects(state);
```

To this:

```
store.commit("updateSubjects");
```

And it works!  :-)

Comment: ok, there was an error from stackoverflow when I tried to mark it as accepted:
`You can accept your own answer in 2 days`

Comment: This is what I meant by "when you can".